# output *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference. System verilog

Tags: system-verilog

```
class tx;
  pkt p;
  int j;
  function new ( pkt p);
    p = new();
    j =10;
  endfunction
  task copy(pkt p);
    this.p = new p;
  endtask
endclass :tx

initial
  begin  
  tx t1,t2;
  pkt p;

  t1 =new();
  p = new();

  p.i=256;

  t2= new t1;
  t2.j=20;
  t2.copy(p);

  $display(t1.j);
  $display(t2.j);
  $display(p.i);
  $display(t1.p.i);
  $display(t2.p.i);

  t1.p.i=221;
  $display(t1.p.i);
  $display(t2.p.i);
 end
 endprogram
```

Why this code is not giving output. when i change t1 = new (p). it works fine 
but give error for few lines

> ncsim> run 10 20 256 ncsim: *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference.

While it doesn't print for 
       $display(t1.p.i);
       $display(t2.p.i);

Comment: Which line is giving you the error, and what do you expect it do output? and what is pkt?

Comment: t1 =new();   was error  line .code somehow works when I put  t1 = new (p). I don't know what output this code will give. But Cadence gives few output like 10 , 20 ,256 . Then it gives  ncsim: *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference.   as error.   I expect output of  $display(t1.p.i);

Comment: I expect output of $display(t1.p.i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null pointer errors occurs when trying to access a object that doesn't exist.

For the case of `t1 = new()`, there should be an warning in the compile/elaboration log. Something along the lines of missing input p. Changing `t1 = new()` to `t1 = new(p)` may appear to change resolve the error on that line, but `t1.p` is still null. This is because input variable has the same name of the as a member variable. When you `new`ed the `p` inside `tx`'s `new` it used the input variable because it was closer in scope. Since you assigned a new object to a input handle, the original handle is not pointing to the same object. It would be pointing the the same object if you used you defined the directionality as `inout` or `ref` instead as an inferred input. Still the member `p` would be null.

Solutions:

1. Change `tx`'s `function new ( pkt p);` to `function new ();`. The input `p` doesn't appear to be doing anything so there is no reason to have it. `p = new()` will be assigned to `tx`'s member variable since there is no name conflict.
2. Change `p = new()` to `this.p = new()` in `tx`'s `new` method. This makes it explicit that the new will apply to the member variable, not the local.
3. Do both solutions 1 and 2.
4. If you need both `p`s and you do not want to do the above, then rename one and use accordingly.